# python-neat example broken

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm trying to run the following code from [python neat](https://neat-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/xor_example.html) which allows you to apply genetic algorithms to neural networks. It is a very interesting concept only I cannot get the example code to run.

```
"""
2-input XOR example -- this is most likely the simplest possible example.
"""

from __future__ import print_function
import os
import neat
import visualize

# 2-input XOR inputs and expected outputs.
xor_inputs = [(0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0), (1.0, 1.0)]
xor_outputs = [   (0.0,),     (1.0,),     (1.0,),     (0.0,)]


def eval_genomes(genomes, config):
    for genome_id, genome in genomes:
        genome.fitness = 4.0
        net = neat.nn.FeedForwardNetwork.create(genome, config)
        for xi, xo in zip(xor_inputs, xor_outputs):
            output = net.activate(xi)
            genome.fitness -= (output[0] - xo[0]) ** 2


def run(config_file):
    # Load configuration.
    config = neat.Config(neat.DefaultGenome, neat.DefaultReproduction,
                         neat.DefaultSpeciesSet, neat.DefaultStagnation,
                         config_file)

    # Create the population, which is the top-level object for a NEAT run.
    p = neat.Population(config)

    # Add a stdout reporter to show progress in the terminal.
    p.add_reporter(neat.StdOutReporter(True))
    stats = neat.StatisticsReporter()
    p.add_reporter(stats)
    p.add_reporter(neat.Checkpointer(5))

    # Run for up to 300 generations.
    winner = p.run(eval_genomes, 300)

    # Display the winning genome.
    print('\nBest genome:\n{!s}'.format(winner))

    # Show output of the most fit genome against training data.
    print('\nOutput:')
    winner_net = neat.nn.FeedForwardNetwork.create(winner, config)
    for xi, xo in zip(xor_inputs, xor_outputs):
        output = winner_net.activate(xi)
        print("input {!r}, expected output {!r}, got {!r}".format(xi, xo, output))

    node_names = {-1:'A', -2: 'B', 0:'A XOR B'}
    visualize.draw_net(config, winner, True, node_names=node_names)
    visualize.plot_stats(stats, ylog=False, view=True)
    visualize.plot_species(stats, view=True)

    p = neat.Checkpointer.restore_checkpoint('neat-checkpoint-4')
    p.run(eval_genomes, 10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Determine path to configuration file. This path manipulation is
    # here so that the script will run successfully regardless of the
    # current working directory.
    local_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    config_path = os.path.join(local_dir, 'config-feedforward')
    run(config_path)
```

Here is the config file

```
#--- parameters for the XOR-2 experiment ---#

[NEAT]
fitness_criterion     = max
fitness_threshold     = 3.9
pop_size              = 150
reset_on_extinction   = False

[DefaultGenome]
# node activation options
activation_default      = sigmoid
activation_mutate_rate  = 0.0
activation_options      = sigmoid

# node aggregation options
aggregation_default     = sum
aggregation_mutate_rate = 0.0
aggregation_options     = sum

# node bias options
bias_init_mean          = 0.0
bias_init_stdev         = 1.0
bias_max_value          = 30.0
bias_min_value          = -30.0
bias_mutate_power       = 0.5
bias_mutate_rate        = 0.7
bias_replace_rate       = 0.1

# genome compatibility options
compatibility_disjoint_coefficient = 1.0
compatibility_weight_coefficient   = 0.5

# connection add/remove rates
conn_add_prob           = 0.5
conn_delete_prob        = 0.5

# connection enable options
enabled_default         = True
enabled_mutate_rate     = 0.01

feed_forward            = True
initial_connection      = full

# node add/remove rates
node_add_prob           = 0.2
node_delete_prob        = 0.2

# network parameters
num_hidden              = 0
num_inputs              = 2
num_outputs             = 1

# node response options
response_init_mean      = 1.0
response_init_stdev     = 0.0
response_max_value      = 30.0
response_min_value      = -30.0
response_mutate_power   = 0.0
response_mutate_rate    = 0.0
response_replace_rate   = 0.0

# connection weight options
weight_init_mean        = 0.0
weight_init_stdev       = 1.0
weight_max_value        = 30
weight_min_value        = -30
weight_mutate_power     = 0.5
weight_mutate_rate      = 0.8
weight_replace_rate     = 0.1

[DefaultSpeciesSet]
compatibility_threshold = 3.0

[DefaultStagnation]
species_fitness_func = max
max_stagnation       = 20
species_elitism      = 2

[DefaultReproduction]
elitism            = 2
survival_threshold = 0.2
```

Lastly here is the version of python-neat I have installed

```
pip show neat-python
Name: neat-python
Version: 0.92
Summary: A NEAT (NeuroEvolution of Augmenting Topologies) implementation
Home-page: https://github.com/CodeReclaimers/neat-python
```

Could anyone please help me resolve the following error? Because so far what I have tried is installing from github and installing from pip and both give me the same error on the example code. I have also tried variant code but i get the same error.

```
 ****** Running generation 0 ****** 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "driver.py", line 34, in <module>
    winner = p.run(eval_genomes)
  File "/home/j/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/neat_python-0.92-py3.8.egg/neat/population.py", line 88, in run
  File "driver.py", line 18, in eval_genomes
    output = net.activate(xi)
  File "/home/j/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/neat_python-0.92-py3.8.egg/neat/nn/feed_forward.py", line 13, in activate
RuntimeError: Expected 3 inputs, got 2
```

Comment: It looks like the project hasn't been active in ~5 years. I don't want to discourage you, but how much of your energy can you put toward this?

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes I have lots of free time atm.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an example code for a newer version.
Example Source
NOTE: This page shows the source and configuration file for the current version of neat-python available on GitHub. If you are using the version 0.92 installed from PyPI, make sure you get the script and config file from the archived source for that release.

I checked your code in the https://neat-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/xor_example.html and it looks the same but check your version. Try to access the archived source for that release:
https://github.com/CodeReclaimers/neat-python/releases/tag/v0.92

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Determine path to configuration file. This path manipulation is
    # here so that the script will run successfully regardless of the
    # current working directory.
    local_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    config_path = os.path.join(local_dir, 'config-feedforward') #<----
    run(config_path)
```

in this "if" you will change the name of the config file as 'config-feedforward.txt' instead of 'config-feedforward'